# Is it possible to share bitmap from one device to another without losing quality?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

After searching a lot i found out that `Bitmap` can be shared by encoding it using `Base64`. But it gets distorted when it is zoomed using a `Zoom Image View`. I know that i can save it on `Firebase Storage` but that will populated my database too much and that will cost too much. I am actually making a chat app and in that they will send the images in messages. So how is it possible ? Hope i am clear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course you can share without loss of quality. I wonder what you are doing that you loose quality.

Comment: `i found out that Bitmap can be shared by decoding it using Base64` You mean encoding. But i have no idea why you would encode anything as you would always have 30% more bytes to transfer then.

Comment: Yes I meant encoding.  So what is the solution ?

Comment: Well ... unless / until you can explain how / where the loss of resolution is occurring in your app, I don't think we can answer that.  (But Base64 encoding / decoding doesn't affect the resolution at all.  And zooming an image doesn't either.  The "distortion" is most likely due to going beyond the actual resolution of the image that you are looking at via the viewer.  The loss of resolution happened somewhere else.  Possibly even when the user created the image.)

Comment: i am not sure about that. but can you please tell can a bitmap be shared from device to device